# Определить пропадание сигнала от устройства

Tags: алгоритм, golang

Имеются устройства которые отправляет показания на сервер в виде Post запроса json, сервер в свою очередь парсит данные и записывает в базу данных. Данные представлены в виде разницы времени записи в базу и текущим временем сервера в секундах. Ниже представлены данные последних 4 запросов в базу и их разницей во времени, последняя запись была 9 секунд назад, следующая 19 секунд и так далее. Ниже показана нормальная ситуация когда устройство отправляет данные в пределах от 0 до 10 секунд.

```
im_948727345_15620eb732f93f81  Разница №1 =  9
im_948727345_15620eb732f93f81  Разница №2 =  19
im_948727345_15620eb732f93f81  Разница №3 =  29
im_948727345_15620eb732f93f81  Разница №4 =  39
```

А есть и такие устройства которые не могут отправить данные по разным причинам и ситуация там примерно такая:

```
im_948727345_2c773a6ebfa6e8fa  Разница №1 =  21382
im_948727345_2c773a6ebfa6e8fa  Разница №2 =  21405
im_948727345_2c773a6ebfa6e8fa  Разница №3 =  21420
im_948727345_2c773a6ebfa6e8fa  Разница №4 =  23911
```

Можно просто сравнивать разницу допустим с числом 60(секунд) если более 60  то у нас около 60 секунд нет данных от устройства, восстановление сигнала также можно сравнивать с числом 60 и если разница меньше то сигнал восстановился. А хотелось бы получить информацию только в те моменты когда разница во времени увеличилась и  уменьшилась. Если мы будем брать другое число отличное от 60 не будет результата, будет усредненное число, а нужно наблюдать увеличение и уменьшение.
Я хочу сделать чтобы при значениях  первое между 40 и 49, второе 50 и 59, третье 60 и 69, четвертое 70 и 79 - срабатывал сигнал о том что с устройства не поступают данные. А при значениях первое больше 120 , второе от 0 до 9, третье от 10 до 19, четвертое от 20 до 29 - срабатывал сигнал  о том что сигнал с устройства восстановился - не могу это сформулировать на языке golang....

Comment: Ну так а в чем проблема? в выборе правильного числа вместо 60?

Comment: Если мы будем брать другое число отличное от 60 не будет результата, будет усредненное число, а нужно наблюдать увеличение и уменьшение.  Я хочу сделать чтобы при значениях  первое между 40 и 49, второе 50 и 59, третье 60 и 69, четвертое 70 и 79 - срабатывал сигнал о том что с устройства не поступают данные. А при значениях первое больше 120 , второе от 0 до 9, третье от 10 до 19, четвертое от 20 до 29 - срабатывал сигнал  о том что сигнал с устройства восстановился - не могу это сформулировать на языке golang....

Comment: если нет  данных от устройства, то похоже никто в базу ничего не запишет. Поэтому, похоже нужно проверять время последней записи в базу для данного устройства. Если оно больше определенного значения - подымайте флаг "нет соединения". если оно окажется маленьким и флаг поднят - восстанавилось

Comment: я делаю реал-тайм маниторинг для больших промышленных машин. задача примерно как у вас. если данные метрики выше\ниже чем хочется, то нужно отправлять нотификацию. метрики присылают данные каждые 2 секунды. 
алгоритм такой. берется watcher, в отдельной горутине каждые N секунд берет занные из базы. сотртирует по времени. смотрит на их значение. если что-то плохо, то отправляет нотификацию. создает алерты и т.п.